# Integrate Machine Learning algorithms written in Python into a Hadoop cluster

Tags: python, machine-learning, hadoop, scikit-learn

After creating a Hadoop cluster that provides data to a Cassandra database, I would like to integrate into the Hadoop architecture some Machine Learning algorithms that I have coded in Python using the SciKit-Learn library in order to schedule when to run these algorithms to the data stored in Cassandra automatically.

Does anyone know how to proceed or any bibliography that could help me?

I have tried to search for information but I have only found that I can use Mahout, but the algorithms I want to apply are the ones I wrote in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, Cassandra isn't part of Hadoop, and Hadoop isn't required for it.

Scikit is fine for small datasets, but to scale an algorithm into Hadoop specifically, your dataset will be distributed, and therefore cannot load into Scikit directly.

You would need to use PySpark w/ Pandas Integration as a starting point, Spark MLlib has several algorithms of its own, and you can optionally deploy that code into Hadoop YARN.